# Is there a way I can put a string array member in front of ".structurevariable"?

Tags: c++

So to save myself a headache (and creating a headache instead), I'm trying to put a string array member in front of a structure variable of the same name, but it's not working and giving me an error of:  std::string {aka class std::basic_string}’ has no member named ‘maxPerDay'"

I'm trying to get it to where it reads the string array value and makes it so it enters the value of that structure value, if that makes sense.

```
struct monthlyData{
    int planesLanded;
    int planesDeparted;
    int maxPerDay;
    int leastPerDay;
    };
```

That's what my structure consists of.

I declared the monthlyData variables below:

```
monthlyData Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec;
```

Furthermore, this is what my string array looks like:

```
string monthNames[12] = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
```

And this is the loop I'm trying to implement that I hoped would save me some time from having to code it manually:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter planes landed for " << monthNames[i] << endl;
        cin >> monthNames[i].planesLanded;
        cout << "Enter planes departed for " << monthNames[i] << endl;
        cin >> monthNames[i].planesDeparted;
        cout << "Enter max departures per day in " << monthNames[i] << endl;
        cin >> monthNames[i].maxPerDay;
        cout << "Enter least per day in " << monthNames[i] << endl;
        cin >> monthNames[i].leastPerDay;
    }
```

I just want to have the program allow the user to input the numbers to the corresponding month structures. I just didn't want to be redundant with my code.

Comment: In C++ there is no way to get a variable from a string that contains its name. You need a different approach, like replacing `monthlyData Jan, Feb ...` with an array.

Comment: Not knowing your overall goals, you would probably set up a table of strings for the prompt, paired with the corresponding member pointer.  This is assuming all the struct members are the same type.  The good thing about it is that you just need to update the table instead of going into the `for` loop to update it.

Answer (score 3):

You can build an array "parallel" to the month names with the addresses of those structures:

```
monthlyData *monthAddr[] = { &Jan, &Feb, &Mar, &Apr, &May, &Jun,
                             &Jul, &Aug, &Sep, &Oct, &Nov, &Dec };
```

then you can input it with

```
cout << "Enter planes landed for " << monthNames[i] << endl;
cin >> monthAddr[i]->planesLanded;
```

A better option is however to avoid repeating yourself and just use for example an `std::map` from month names to month structures instead of using explicit variables

```
std::map<std::string, monthlyData> data;
```

then you can use `data["Jan"]` instead of `Jan`.
Using a map you can also index it with `data[monthNames[i]]`.

Simpler than a map would be just an array of 12 structures, but then your code would need to use numeric indexes (e.g. `data[0]` instead of `Jan`):

```
monthlyData data[12];
```

but you could create references to make your code more readable if you need to refer to individual names

```
auto& Jan = data[0];
auto& Feb = data[1];
auto& Mar = data[2];
auto& Apr = data[3];
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying to do some kind of reflection with your code. C++ has very limited support for code reflection, and even in languages with more robust support, this isn't a terribly ideomatic solution anyways.

You should just associate the month name with the data.

```
struct MonthlyData{//I've renamed the struct to CapitalCase
    MonthlyData(std::string month) :
        month(std::move(month)), planesLanded(0), planesDeparted(0), maxPerDay(0), leastPerDay(0)
        {}
    std::string month;
    int planesLanded;
    int planesDeparted;
    int maxPerDay;
    int leastPerDay;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<MonthlyData> vec { 
        {"Jan"},
        {"Feb"},
        {"Mar"},
        {"Apr"},
        {"May"},
        {"Jun"},
        {"Jul"},
        {"Aug"},
        {"Sep"},
        {"Oct"},
        {"Nov"},
        {"Dec"},
    };

    for (auto & data : vec) {
        cout << "Enter planes landed for " << data.month << endl;
        cin >> data.planesLanded;
        cout << "Enter planes departed for " << data.month << endl;
        cin >> data.planesDeparted;
        cout << "Enter max departures per day in " << data.month << endl;
        cin >> data.maxPerDay;
        cout << "Enter least per day in " << data.month << endl;
        cin >> data.leastPerDay;
    }
}
```